# Listview to Recycler view conversion

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I want to implement a `RecyclerView` version of a `ListView` where the given code below retrieves images from the SQLite database for displaying them in a list.
Please help me to understand how I can achieve that.

```
public class dataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Contact> mcontact;
    public dataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contact){
        super(context, R.layout.listcontacts, contact);
        this.context=context;
        this.mcontact=contact;
    }

    public  class  Holder{
        TextView nameFV;
        ImageView pic;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Contact data = getItem(position);
        Holder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new Holder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listcontacts, parent, false);

            viewHolder.nameFV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewer);
            viewHolder.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();  
        viewHolder.nameFV.setText("Image Title: "+data.getFName());
        viewHolder.pic.setImageBitmap(convertToBitmap(data.getImage()));
        // Return the completed view to render on screen
        return convertView;
    }

    private Bitmap convertToBitmap(byte[] b){
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple adapter i used it in my project . hopefully you will learn from it and don't want us to code for you.

```
    package com.example.contactexchange.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.contactexchange.R;

import java.util.List;


public class ChildrenRvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildrenRvAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    private Context context;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    public ChildrenRvAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.children_rv_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String name = mData.get(position);
        holder.tv_name.setText(name);
        setAnimation(holder.itemView, position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView tv_name;
        Button btn_remove;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
            btn_remove = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_remove);
            btn_remove.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        Cursor c = null;

    }

    private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
        // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
        if (position > lastPosition) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left);
            viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
            lastPosition = position;
        }
    }
}
```

usage :

```
childrenRvAdapter = new ChildrenRvAdapter(c, dataSource);
    childrenRvAdapter.setClickListener(this);
    rv_childrens.setAdapter(childrenRvAdapter);
```